# How to add style to parent <li> item if child <ul> exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a menu in advance to be seen whether there is a double nesting.

```
<ul class="parent">
 <li class="child"></li>
 <li class="child">
  <ul slass="nesting">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li class="child"></li>
</ul>
```

So ul class="nesting" hidden by default but appears during the hover of li class="child".
I want to make another design on the li class="child" which have a nested ul.
Another words how can i show nesting before hover by the means of Javascript/JQuery?

Thnaks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [:has() selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$("li.child:has(ul.nesting)").addClass("myclass");
```

In English:

If `li.child` has `ul.nesting` as a descendant (child), add class `myclass` to that `li.child` element.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this would be having something like:

```
 var $doubleNesting = $('li.child').find('ul');
```

And then add some css styling on the current li, or something like that.